# What is the difference between \d and \p{Digit}?

Tags: ruby, regex

While I have been using `\p{Alpha}` and `\p{Space}` for quite some time in my regular expressions I just came across `\p{Digit}`, but I couldn't find any information about what the up- or downsides are compared to the normal `\d` that I normally use. What are the key differences between those to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\d` matches only ASCII digits, i.e. it is equivalent to the class `[0-9]`. `\p{Digit}` matches the same characters as `\d` plus any other Unicode character that represents a digit. For example to match the arabic zero (code point U+0660):

```
"\u0660"
# => "٠"

"\u0660" =~ /\d/
# => nil

"\u0660" =~ /\p{Digit}/
# => 0
```

Comment: `\p{Digit}` matches both ascii and unicode digits `123٠12321١‎٢` [check here](http://rubular.com/r/Z0gxZujC5Z)